# Best way to access the values of a nested hash

Tags: ruby

Here is my hash:

```
{"funds"=>
  {"0"=>
    {"sector"=>"6555",
     "fund_id"=>"4308",
     "percent"=>"20.0",
     "fund_distribution_id"=>"315304"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get the values for `sector`, `fund_id` etc?

If I do the following I get an undefined method '[]' nil:NilClass because it's looking for the 'sector' key of '0'

```
params[:funds].each_with_index do |f, index|
    puts f[index]['sector']
end
```

Answer (score 2):

if

```
x = {"funds"=>
      {"0"=>
        {"sector"=>"6555", 
         "fund_id"=>"4308", 
         "percent"=>"20.0", 
         "fund_distribution_id"=>"315304"
        }
      }
    }
```

, then you can get value of sector and fund_id by

```
  x["funds"]["0"]["sector"]
  x["funds"]["0"]["fund_id"]
```

Comment: but say i have multiple nested hashes as in the example, how do i loop over and get the values mentioned?

Comment: if you have multiple nested hash, then you can loop over them  like     x["funds"].each {|arr| pp arr[1]["fund_id"]}

Comment: x["funds"].each { |arr| } will give acces to key and value pairs inside as an associative array. but x["funds"].each {| k,v| } will give access to individual keys and values as k and v

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x['funds'].values.map{ |fund| fund['sector'] }
x['funds'].values.map{ |fund| fund['fund_id'] }
# etc.
```

Where "x" is your given hash

Answer (score 2):

I usually extend the `Hash` class with this:

```
class Hash
  def deep_fetch *args
    args.inject(self) { |h, val| h.try(:[], val) }
  end
end
```

and then you can call:

```
my_hash.deep_fetch 'funds', 0, 'sector'
```

to get funds->0->sector or you'll get `nil` if its not there

or in your case:

```
(my_hash.deep_fetch('funds', 0) || {}).each{ ... }
```

Comment: Very nice!, I think this way: `def deep_fetch *args
    args.inject(self) { |h, val| h.try(:[], val) }
    end` is more rubyist way

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `index.to_s` to get to your hash with string hash, as shown.

If you want all values, you can use `hash.values`.

If you don't want to get error for nil use `hash.try(:[], value)`